# Looking for Design Pattern to Automate Repeated Task such as Login/Logout

Tags: c#, design-patterns, httpclient

I'm looking to a design pattern to help simplify my code.

My code is using HttpClient to call a web API that gets or posts information, but each session requires a login call first where a cookie is returned as ID, and a logout call is made at the end to close the connection. So my web API class looks like this:

```
public class APIHelper 
{
    public HttpClient myClient { get; set; }

    public async void Login()
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.PostAsync("loginAddress", "loginInput"))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                    
                //save cookie
            }
        }
    }

    public async void Logout()
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.PostAsync("logoutAddress", ""))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                    
                //session ends
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetOrder()  {...}

    public void NewOrder(object OrderData)  {...}

    public void GetCustomer()   {...}

    public void NewCustomer(object CustomerData)    {...}
}
```

And to use them, I would simply call them in order:

```
public Main()
{
    APIHelper.Login();
    APIHelper.GetOrder();   //or NewOrder, or GetCustomer, or any other actual API calls
    APIHelper.Logout();
}
```

Is there anyway I can place the Login/Logout calls inside each of the actual API calls so I don't have to type them up for each call? Ideally I just have to set up the structure once, then for whatever API calls I create, the system will automatically call the Login/Logout at beginning/end. Which design pattern addresses this kind of issue?  Any simple example would be very helpful!

Thank you. SC

=====================================

Edit: Trying out Dymanoid's suggestion

Thanks for the quick reply! I think it should work, but I got another wrinkle: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'APIHelper.GetOrder()'

Looking at the new code, it seems I need the myClient object (which is a HttpClient object) through out the session:

```
public void DoMyJob(Action job)
{            
    var myClient = new APIHelper();     //initiates a HttpClient object

    myClient.Login();
    try
    {       
        job();
    }
    finally
    {
        myClient.Logout();
    }
}
```

But when calling the job function from outside:

```
DoMyJob(APIHelper.GetOrder);
```

I don't have the object yet.  Is this easy to work around?  Sorry I didn't make that clear in the OP, my actual original call looks like this:

```
var myClient = new APIHelper();
myClient.Login();
myClient.GetOrder();
myClient.Logout();
```

But thanks to your suggestion, I think it's better to put the initilization inside the DoMyJob method.

Answer (score 6):

Use template method + strategy for that.

```
void DoMyJob(Action job)
{
    APIHelper.Login();
    try
    {
        job();
    }
    finally
    {
        APIHelper.Logout();
    }
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
DoMyJob(() => APIHelper.GetOrder());
```

or

```
DoMyJob(APIHelper.GetOrder);
```

or

```
DoMyJob(() => { APIHelper.GetOrder(); APIHelper.NewOrder(); } );
```